# Turning map layers on and off

Tags: maps, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server

If its not one problem its another.  I've been looking at this all day and dont know what is going wrong here.  I again have a map with two layers a county layer and a msa layer.  I have two links on the page one that says county other that says msa.  On the click of either link I want to turn one layer of the map off and display on the correct layer.  Here is the click event:

```
$('.map-type-link').live('click', function () {
    params.display_region_type = parseInt($(this).attr('region_type'));

    if (params.display_region_type == 1) {

        app.currentFl = app.featureLayers[0];

    }
    else {

        app.currentFl = app.MSAfl;            
        app.flVis.setVisibility(false);
        app.MSAfl.setVisibility(true);
        app.currentFl.redraw();                        

    }
```

});

Right not just clicking the county the app.flvis is still visible.

Here where the feature layers are created:

```
dojo.forEach(app.layersUrls, function (info, idx) {
    app.featureLayers[idx] = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(
        app.layersUrls[idx], {
            mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            outFields: app.outFields[idx],
            opacity: 0.80
            }
        );       

    app.featureLayers[idx].setRenderer(br);

    //create min and max scales when layers load
    dojo.connect(app.featureLayers[idx], 'onLoad', function () {
        app.featureLayers[idx].minScale = app.layerScales[idx].min;
        app.featureLayers[idx].maxScale = app.layerScales[idx].max;
    });//ends connections 

    //add THIS feature layer to the map
    app.map.addLayer(app.featureLayers[idx]);
```

Answer (score 0):

(I'm making assumptions of what all your variables mean.)

To turn on the MSA layer, you have four lines of code (in the else statement):

```
app.currentFl = app.MSAfl;            
app.flVis.setVisibility(false);
app.MSAfl.setVisibility(true);
app.currentFl.redraw();
```

In the if statement, you only have one line of code, a line that wouldn't turn any layers on or off:

```
app.currentFl = app.featureLayers[0];
```

Instead, I think you need to follow the example of what you did in the else statement:

```
app.currentFl = app.flVis;            
app.MSAfl.setVisibility(false);
app.flVis.setVisibility(true);
app.currentFl.redraw();
```

That assumes that app.flVis is your county layer, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: was a larger issue at hand as to why that wasnt just hiding the intended layer